# Why I get wrong value of frame width in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to customise a rounded image in a UITableViewCell. However, I cannot get the correct width of my image set in storyboard. Why?

[image]

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!


var photo: Photo! {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    userImageView.layer.cornerRadius =  0.5 * self.userImageView.frame.width 
    print("\(self.userImageView.frame.width)") // print out 1000.0 !! WHY?
    userImageView.layer.cornerRadius =  24 // IT WORKS!
}



private func updateUI() {
    self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: photo.name)
    self.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: photo.user)
    self.captionLabel.text = photo.caption
    print("\(self.userImageView.frame.width)") // print out 1000.0 !! Same here
}
}
```

Comment: The `autolayout` of your tableview may effect its cells frame.If you use `autolayout`, you had better not use frame.

Comment: My guess is that you are doing this at the wrong time. I know this is `layoutSubviews` but it may still be that `userImageView` has not yet been layed out. `layoutSubviews` has to percolate all the way down the view hierarchy before that happens. You have not explained where this `layoutSubviews` _is_. Where is it? What's the view hierarchy?

Comment: I've updated my explanation with code.

Comment: You can get the correct frame in ViewDidAppear. You may get correct frame in ViewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is well after I put these code in **layoutIfNeeded()**

```
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
    userImageView.layer.cornerRadius =  self.userImageView.frame.width / 2
    userImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    userImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    userImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your statement

```
print("\(self.userImageView.frame.width)") // print out 1000.0 !! Same here
```

with

```
print("\(self.userImageView.frame.size.width)")
```

Because `frame` is type of `CGRect`

```
public struct CGRect {
    public var origin: CGPoint
    public var size: CGSize
    public init()
    public init(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize)
}
```

In that structure `CGSize` has following structure

```
public struct CGSize {
    public var width: CGFloat
    public var height: CGFloat
    public init()
    public init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also

```
var imageWidth = userImageView.frame.size.width
```

May be this will help you for getting image width.

Answer (score 0):

Take equal width and height.After write below then u will get exact rounded image.
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius =  imageView.frame.width / 2
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true